# Problems from probability and martingale 6.7

Tags: probability

I 've read the text of the section and at the end of the section. It mentions **vector property of** $\mathcal{L}^p$, it shows that
$$(a+b)^p \le [2max(a,b)]^p \le 2^p(a^p+b^p)$$ and conclude that the $\mathcal{L}^p$ space is a vector space.
I can't get the author's idea since all I've learned about vector space is its linear property. But here the inequality I don't know what it means accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f,g \in L^p(\Omega)$. Apply the inequality with $a = |f(x)|$ and $b = |g(x)|$. Integrate both sides and conclude that

$$\int_\Omega |f+g|^p \leqslant\int_{\Omega}(|f|+|g|)^p \leqslant 2^p \left(\int_\Omega |f|^p + \int_\Omega |g|^p \right) < \infty$$

Hence, $f+g \in L^p(\Omega)$. This along with $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ implies $\alpha f \in L^p(\Omega)$ for any real $\alpha$ proves that this is a linear (vector) space.